# How to detect/recover from slow SQL server I/O in a C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# .NET based program which runs 24/7 checking for and processing data in SQL Server.  This program runs fine all day long, but a little after 2AM each morning, something happens on my customer's server which causes SQL to report slow I/O.  SQL reports something like the following in its logs:

> SQL Server has encountered 129 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf] in database id 2.  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000D9C.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x00000007ce0000

There are usually several of these message logged each morning, one after another.

Sometimes my program loses the connection to SQL server and exits, after which it is automatically restarted by a service.  Other times my program stops responding and I have to manually kill and restart the process in the morning.

My customer's IT has not been able to identify the cause of the slowdown, so I'm trying to change my program or connection settings to reliably detect the problem and exit, or overcome it in some other way. 
 I've searched, but can't find anything online related to this sort of issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try not having a persistent connection to SQL but instead open it, do your work and close it (best practice). Ultimately, it feels a bit like youre asking the wrong thing - you're asking "how can I make my code tolerant of the crashes that happen when SQL server runs slowly" when you should be asking "how can I make my code tolerant of a sqlserver that runs slowly" (simple: set a short timeout, open conenction, do stuff, close connection, catch exception, go back to sleep for a while)

Comment: @DaleK the question is not about finding the cause of the problem with SQL Server and preventing it so much as it's about making the application tolerate the crashes it experiences when SQLS goes slow

Comment: @CaiusJard Completely agree. My short version: don't keep connections open if they are idle.  Do expect connections to close unexpectedly for a variety of reasons and handle it gracefully.  Use transactions to protect data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a little different solution as you said any help would be appreciated.

As I understand **you do not know what is causing the problem** and in my opinion you should **focus on getting the knowledge** what it is.

In your situation the best would be to ask your customer to set **SQL Server Profiler** for the time that is being under suspection that causes the problems. This is the tool that harvest all SQL Server activity. I have used this many times at my work.

For the question how to set SQL Server Profiler you would find easily the answer on google. This is quite easy and intuitive.
Be prepare to catch lots of queries, but you can filter them easily too.

**Based on the logs in SQL Server Profiler you would know what is causing the problem** and you can **fix it** in your application.

Let me know if this helped.